# Changing the value of a label in a tab control

Tags: c#, label

I have a label inside a tab control, which functions as the "placeholder" for a randomly assigned ID number. When the user chooses to load the Medical Record Form, a random number is supposed to be assigned to the ID label, altering its text from 'Record ID Here', to the assigned number.

I have another label, which is not in a tab control, but is laid out the same way (both are in the constructor of their respective forms), and it functions perfectly. Why is this issue happening, and what can be done to sort it?

The code for the label residing in a tab control:

```
medicalRecordIDRand = new Random();
        medicalRecordID = medicalRecordIDRand.Next(100000, 999999);

        lblMedicalRecordID.Text = medicalRecordID.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("To add a new medical record, please choose 'Records', then 'New Record'. A unique ID number for this medical record has already been pre-assigned.", "For Your Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        lblMedicalRecordID.Text = medicalRecordID.ToString();
```

The code for the label that works correctly:

```
patientIDRand = new Random();

        patientIDNumber = patientIDRand.Next(1002, 9999);
        MessageBox.Show("To add a new patient, please choose 'File', then 'New Patient'. A unique ID number for this patient has already been pre-assigned to this record.", "For Your Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        lblPatientIDProper.Text = patientIDNumber.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi. The issue is I cannot get the medical record ID label to change from its placeholder text, when it is assigned a random number, and show that random number.

Comment: Did you make sure that the placeholder text is not getting assigned again to `lblMedicalRecordID` after the random number?

Comment: If it helps, I added the placeholder text by using the "Properties" menu for the Medical Record ID Label in Visual Studio, the code does not then re-assign the placeholder text to the label, as such code is not present there.

Comment: The posted code in itself is correct.  I suspect it's either not getting executed or the value is being overwritten later in the code.

Comment: How can I get it to execute, please? For that form, there is other code (mutators and accessors, but that is it).

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake, I was looking at another tab. Thanks wdosanjos for trying to help, it is mcuh appreciated. All is working as designed now.